# WooCommerce cart table summary

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, cart

I'm looking to change the table summary like image size and the position of it want and other in table want to add an icon to the remove item like that, but I'm trying to get around it for 2 days nothing bought Elementor pro and Crockblock nothing also, can anyone help me with it ?

That's the table I'm talking about:

[image]

Nothing happened can't get around WooCommerce.